# copy files from one path to another path in linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-copy

I am trying to copy files from one path to another path. I have a text file which has all names of files in the following pattern:

```
file-1.txt
file-2.pdf
file-3.ppt
....
```

I created a `.sh` file with the following code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
file=`cat filenames.txt`;
fromPath='/root/Backup/upload/';
toPath='/root/Desktop/custom/upload/';
for i in $file;
do
 filePath=$fromPath$i
 #echo $filePath
 if [ -e $filePath ];
 then
   echo $filePath
   yes | cp -rf $filePath $toPath
 else
   echo 'no files'
 fi
done
```

The above code is copying only the last file name from the text instead of all to the destination path.

Comment: protip: ` syntax is deprecated. use $() instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file=/path/to/filenames.txt
fromPath=/root/Backup/upload/
toPath=/root/Desktop/custom/upload/

cd "$fromPath" && xargs mv -t "$toPath" < "$file"
```

Comment: The problem was that each line in the text file was terminating differently instead of just `\n`.. may be like `\n\r`.. I run `sed 's:\r$::' -i filename.txt` at the text file path and run my script again. which worked fine. Anyway thanks for your short answer +1 :)

Comment: @Mr_Green If your file had \n\r as new line characters, then may be it was copied from a windows machine. You may run the command "dos2unix filename" and then run your original script. It should work then.

Comment: @GautamSomani yes it was copied from a windows machine. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at `rsync`, if you're not already familiar with it.  This looks like a problem that shouldn't really require a script of its own.

Take a look [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/), or use your Google foo.

The `rsync` option you need is probably `--files-from`.

The `rsync` incantation will be something like:

```
rsync --files-from filenames.txt /root/Backup/upload /root/Desktop/custom/upload
```